# Take screenshot from a view of AVFoundation programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am running a video stream by using AVFoundation class, and I am placing an imageview on that to simulate some thing. So is it possible to take screen shot of the simulation. What's happening by using the earlier specified methods is I am getting only a view and a image view but there is no current video image given out byt the camera, only the image I put is visible in the photo saved into the library.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..... it will be help 4 u , This code will be write when Videos are Running

```
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);


(or)

 UIImage *thumbnail;

     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer1= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  initWithContentURL:movieURL];
  [moviePlayer1 play];
  thumbnail = [[moviePlayer1 thumbnailImageAtTime:10 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame] retain];
  [moviePlayer1 stop];
  [moviePlayer1 release];
```

It will give image

Comment: Ya I tried this but it is not working... It works only for views I think not for the video frame view.

Comment: DO you want only image from Video?

Comment: No.. I want image which is placed on the image of the current video stream.. As I told, I am putting an image on the AVCaptureVideo session it belongs to AR part, so I need an that screen shot...